# Crystal Reports Formula in Text Object

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new to formulas and struggling with something. I've got this so far:

```
if {tblcustomer.vat_reseller} = 0 
then VAT: {tblinvoices.vat_multiplier}*100 %
else 
if {tblcustomer.vat_reseller} = 1 
then Reverse charge: Customer to pay the VAT to HMRC
```

There are no errors found but it displays:

> 'VAT: {tblinvoices.vat_multiplier}*100 %' rather than 'VAT: 20%' or
>   'Reverse charge: Customer to pay the VAT to HMRC'

Sorry, it's probably an easy fix (hopefully!) but when I try and tweak the syntax it starts giving me other error such as `a number is required`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values enclosed in quotes are treated as literal strings.

To get the value of `{tblinvoices.vat_multiplier}` multiplied by 100 inside the string, you need to convert it to a string, then concatenate it within the rest of the string - like so:

```
if {tblcustomer.vat_reseller} = 0 
    then "VAT: " & CStr({tblinvoices.vat_multiplier}*100) & " %"
else if {tblcustomer.vat_reseller} = 1 
    then "Reverse charge: Customer to pay the VAT to HMRC"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You've saved me hours of work trying to figure this out. I really appreciate you answering me so quickly. :)

Comment: @SarahV: Glad I could help. You can accept answers to your questions by clicking on the tick mark to the left of the answer.